# How to handle different answers type

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `Risk` model. I want to store predefined `risk`s for each `User`.

1. Are you smoker? yes | no (boolean)
2. How many cigarettes? (integer)
3. Are you diabetic? [since] (string)

   ...

How should I implement `Risk` to make it capable of different types of answers (integer, boolean, string)? And how should the forms look? Right now, I am thinking about `Risk` as below:

```
Risk
  question(string)
  answer_type(integer)
  answer
```

I want to be able to add more questions dynamically in the future.

Comment: Store some kind of container in your DB like MessagePack, Protocol Buffer, JSON etc? But there will be some gotchas if you want indicies on fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my idea is:

```
Risk
  user_id (integer)
  question_id (integer)
  question(string)
  answer_type(integer)
  answer (string)
```

Then if you want make some stats, you will need parse answers depend of answer_type.

```
answer_type -> 1 for text answer
answer_type -> 2 for integer answer
...
```

For example if you want calculate average for integer answer:

```
risks = Risks.where(question_id: 1)
    if risk.answer_type == 2
      total += answer.to_i
    end
    average = total / User.all.count
```

Answer (score -1):

Ideally,

```
question(string)
answer (text)
```

In the Risk model, add a method that returns the answer in its correct format (based) on the question.

```
require 'string_extensions'
Class Risk
 ...

  def correct_answer
    if self.question == 'Are you smoker?'
      self.answer.to_bool # Add the Gist-code in your libs and include this 
    elsif self.question == 'How many cigarettes?'
      self.answer.to_i
    else 
      self.answer
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention. I want to be able add more questions in the future.

Comment: Even if you want to add more questions, the only change you have to do is to the IF-condition. You don't need any more new columns.

Comment: Can someone who has downvoted recommend another solution. Opportunity for me to learn too.